# Violin Plot in R: Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a violin plot for the data below where the x axis has the "heme_frac", y-axis has the "mean_frac" and the groups/fill will be the "Genotype". I uploaded the attached data into r and called it data_long. However I'm getting the error message "Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped" when I try to graph it. So it's not graphing. I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    data_long<-read.csv("data long.csv", header=TRUE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM", check.names=FALSE)
    ggplot(data=data_long, aes(x=heme_frac, y=mean_frac))+ geom_violin(aes(fill=Genotype))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What may be happening here is that one or more of the levels in the Genotype column only has a single observation.  A violin plot will make a shape between the overall range of a continuous variable, the shape will be thickest where there are the most observations.  If there are only two observations, the shape will be a line. And, if there's only a single observation, it won't draw that shape at all and say 'Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.'

```
myData <- data.frame(height = c(2,3,5,1,2,4,6,3), type = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"))
# Plot with plenty of observations within each level of discrete variable 'type'
ggplot(myData, aes(x = type, y = height)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = type))

myData <- data.frame(height = c(2,3,5,1,2,4,6,3), type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"))

# Plot with only a single observation in level 'B'
ggplot(myData, aes(x = type, y = height)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = type))
```

I recommend running `table(data_long$Genotype)` to:

1. Check if there are levels within this discrete variable with only 1 observation
2. Ensure levels which should be equal to each other are being treated as such.  For instance, you're using a special character in this column, maybe the text of some values which should be equal are actually encoded differently.

This is just what I would try!  I hope this is helpful.

Comment: thank you! I ended up abandoning the violin plots altogether because it didn't seem to make sense  for the data I have.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you have a "Genotype" group in which there is only one observation, it is not possible to compute a kernel density estimation for plot (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot)